# Using Async Await in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, async

I am trying to make a reload mechanism in Unity, but the function is in a scriptable object. This means I cannot use Coroutine as it is in MonoBehaviour. I could think of solving with a simple timer with Time.time and Time.deltaTime but for that, I should call the function every frame which seems not too right for me, I'd like to avoid this solution.

I thought about using C#'s built-in Async Await functions but I never used it before and it's quite confusing, I have no idea how to implement it after looking at Microsoft's documentation. I've tried implementing it but I always get an error saying

`The body of 'Weapon.Reload()' cannot be an iterator block because 'void' is not an iterator interface type`

I've done a coroutine implementation so it's easier to see what I want to achieve using Async/Await.

```
public virtual IEnumerator Reload()
{
    if (currentMagazine == magazineSize)
        yield break;

    if (!reloading)
    {
        Debug.Log("Started reloading");
        reloading = true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);
        currentMagazine = magazineSize;
        reloading = false;
        Debug.Log("Reload time over");
    }

    Debug.Log("Finished reloading");
    yield break;
}
```

I want to be able to call this function and just let it do its job over time, without stopping code execution. At first, I tried the simple timer solution with a while loop then realized that just stops code execution so it's not working properly.

How could I do this using C#'s Async/Await?

Comment: This looks like exactly the code that should be in a MonoBehaviour, not in a ScriptableObject, as it's describing/manipulating the current state of a runtime instance of something, not a persistent data asset. Can you show us more of your architecture and why moving this to a MonoBehaviour is not available as a solution in this case?

Comment: It is a scriptable object because I want it anyone to be able to create a simple weapon, but it has virtual methods so if you want more complex behaviour a programmer can just overwrite the shoot or reload function.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111796/discussion-on-question-by-user9578273-using-async-await-in-unity).

Comment: You can pass a MonoBehaviour to the scriptable object. Then the scriptable object use that MonoBehaviour to start the Reload coroutine.

Comment: Related:  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185200/should-i-use-async-await-instead-of-coroutines-in-unity

Answer (score 3):

You can have a coroutine runner MonoBehaviour that runs coroutines defined elsewhere. For example:

```
public class CoroutineRunner : MonoBehaviour {
  private static CoroutineRunner instance;
  public static void RunCoroutine(IEnumerator coroutine) {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new GameObject("runner").AddComponent<CoroutineRunner>();
    }
    instance.StartCoroutine(coroutine);
  }
}
```

And to use it:

```
CoroutineRunner.RunCoroutine(Reload());
```

I know this doesn’t answer your question, but it does solve your problem by challenging your assumption that you cannot use coroutines in a scriptable object (or anywhere you want).

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual async void Reload()
{
    if (currentMagazine == magazineSize)
        return;

    if (!reloading)
    {
        Debug.Log("Started reloading");
        reloading = true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        await Task.Delay(reloadTime * 1000);
        currentMagazine = magazineSize;
        reloading = false;
        Debug.Log("Reload time over");
    }

    Debug.Log("Finished reloading");
}
```

To call, just use `Reload()`.

Comment: I tried doing this but I receive the error message I detailed in my question

Comment: Just use `Reload()` to call it.  I updated my answer.

Comment: The error is coming from Reload's declaration, not calling it

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What line is having the problem?  I wrote that freehand (no compiler).

Comment: The first line, ```public virtual async void Reload()``` the Reload() part is underlined with the error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The body of 'Weapon.Reload()' cannot be an iterator block because 'void' is not an iterator interface type

Comment: Sounds like you have a typo in the body.  Find the word yield, and fix that.