# Is it better to declare a variable for new WaitForSeconds or just create each time in Unity?

Tags: unity

Is it better to declare a variable for new WaitForSeconds or just create each time in Unity?

In other words, is A or B beter?

````
//A

IEnumerator WaitingForGodot(){
  while(!godot){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
  }
}


// B
IEnumerator WaitingForGodot(){
  WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(1f);;
  while(!godot){
    yield return wait;
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Option B involves fewer memory allocations, since each use of `new` with a reference type has to allocate memory and track it for later garbage collection when you're done with it.

These allocations are very small and usually short-lived, so they'll tend to stay in the "Generation 0" garbage collection bucket where allocation and cleanup is relatively fast. The `IEnumerator` instance itself will tend to go here too, unless it's a long-running process; you can't avoid allocation entirely when using coroutines. You don't have to worry about this small overhead most of the time, unless you are making very heavy use of coroutines on a platform where RAM is tight and GC is slow (mobile).

You can go a step further though:

```cs
// C
static readonly WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(1f);

IEnumerator WaitingForGodot(){
  while(!godot){
    yield return wait;
  }
}
```

Now you have one memory allocation for the wait, total, across the entire lifetime of your game, no matter how many times you start this coroutine or how many frames it runs. It also slightly reduces the size of the storage needed for each coroutine's generated `IEnumerator` instance (since they no longer have to store a reference to wait — it's global).

The downside is that now the wait duration is fixed across all iterations, and you pay the construction/allocation cost even if you never actually start this coroutine at all. There's also a minor amount of namespace pollution from taking a function temporary and making it long-lived like this.

Answer (score 1):

Option A is easier to read.

[Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).  If you have performance/garbage issues, then you should revisit.  But until you find a bottleneck, focus on readability and maintainability.

Also, you should use async and await instead of coroutines in [my opinion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185200/should-i-use-async-await-instead-of-coroutines-in-unity).